# How to show newest items on top in firebase database Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my firebase function :-

```
getAllProducts = () => {
    // console.log('getAllProducts')
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.database
        .ref(`products`)
        .once('value')
        .then(async (snapshot) => {
          if (snapshot.exists()) {
            let allProducts = Object.values(snapshot.val())
            let allKeys = Object.keys(snapshot.val())
            await Promise.all(
              allProducts.map(async (item, index) => {
                let items = item
                item = allKeys[index]
                let imageIds = items.images || []
                if (imageIds.length) {
                  if (items.coverImage) {
                    let index = imageIds.indexOf(items.coverImage)
                    var element = imageIds[index]
                    imageIds.splice(index, 0)
                    imageIds.splice(0, 0, element)
                  }
                  let imageUrls = await this.getImages(imageIds)
                  items.images = imageUrls
                }
                console.log(allProducts)
                return items
              }),
            )
            // console.log(allProducts)
            // allProducts = allProducts.filter((item) => item.isApproved === 1)
            resolve(allProducts)
          }
        })
    })
  }
```

And this where i'm calling in page:-

```
 // data from firebase

  useEffect(() => {
    DataBase.getAllProducts().then((response) => {
      console.log('Data fetched user effect', response)
      setIsCalling(true)
      setDataList(response)
    })
  }, [])
```

my query is when i add a product it should be shown on top of the table which means every newest items should be shown on top.

this is my table view:-
https://prnt.sc/1soylw5

Comment: You could add the date that the item was added to the database to the data or use `push` when adding the data, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47541144/7879938)

Comment: Sir could you please explain edit in my code?

Comment: How are you adding items to the database?

Comment: adding through the website